# Intellij Idea - How to update application on Save All action

Tags: intellij-idea

I am running my web-app on Tomcat in IDE Intellij Idea and I need to update my web application every time when I press the **Save All** button. Is it possible? I would like to have the behavior like in IDE Netbeans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, in IntelliJ IDEA you generally do not use the save button, it does it for you. If you want to hot swap (as far as that would be possible), run your webapp in debug mode and hit `ctrl` + `F9`.

Comment: In any case to update my app in debug mode (with external JARs in my project) i use CTRL + F10 to update all resources and classes changed.

Comment: @Ess update all resources is really slow, is there another way to achieve hot swap resources  just like NetBeans does?